# How can I automatically login to a website using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

On Error Resume Next:

```
Const PAGE_LOADED = 4

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Call objIE.Navigate("http://172.25.25.32:8090/")

objIE.Visible = True

Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : Loop

objIE.Document.all.Username.Value = "ashishgi"
objIE.Document.all.Password.Value = "apac2015#"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    msgbox "Error: " & err.Description
End If

Call objIE.Document.all.gaia_loginform.submit

Set objIE = Nothing
```

Comment: The script works fine, but not able to hit the Login button on page.

Answer (score 0):

The `gaia_loginform` is the "form id" of Gmail. Have a look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtQOt.jpg.

Now I think you should get the form name/id of the site (by viewing the source) so that the script can hit the login button.